# How to create the notification for a foreground service with customized data?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm facing a bit of a dilemma with the new foreground service requirements introduced in Android O.

I have a foreground service that creates the foreground notification during `onCreate()` like this:

```
public class FooService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel("channel", "channel", IMPORTANCE_LOW));

        startForeground(42, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel")
                .setContentTitle("Foo")
                .setContentText("Bar")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_sync)
                .build());
    }
}
```

However, an issue arises: What if I need to dynamically pass data to the notification, eg. set a formatted title? Something like this:

```
startForeground(42, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel")
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.formatted_title, intent.getStringExtra("Foobar")))
        ...
```

There's no idiomatic way to pass the argument to the notification since there's no intent passed to `onCreate()`. There is the method `onStartCommand()` that gets an intent as an argument, but there's a catch: `startForeground()` must be called within five seconds of starting the service, but `onStartCommand()` is not guaranteed to be called before the five-second limit is hit. I've experimented with this for a while and it happens about 10% of the time. The only way seems to be to call `startForeground()` during `onCreate()`.

Now, what would be the correct way to approach the dynamic notification content issue?

Comment: We need to use [NotificationManager#notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) with previous notification's ID as 1st parameter to update the notification.

Comment: @Jay Wouldn't that mean that the notification must first be created with static content and later on updated with the dynamic content? Another way I took it is to create the dynamic notification in the activity and then re-create the notification with the same ID in the service, but that would again replace the contents with static data.

Comment: I would register a broadcast receiver in my service and from activity I would broadcast actions with extras(containing update info) for updating the notifications. In my service, I would catch the actions and accordingly, update the notification--which has already been created in onCreate.

Comment: I've tried my above suggested approach and it's working fine.

Comment: The notification can't be created during onCreate because the data is missing.